# Hangfire recurring job throws error after 1-2 times

Tags: hangfire, hangfire-sql

In a .NET Core(2.1) application, it uses Hangfire library(1.7.24) to schedule a recurring job. It uses SQL server as storage for Hangfire. The recurring job works 1-2 times then it throws error. So trying to handle the error means if any error occurred I need to take some action but it doesnt hit C# try-catch block.

Following is code snippet:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Notify", () => new Biz().ScheduleInactiveJob(), "*/30 * * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Utc, "Notify");
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide more details : what does ScheduleInactiveJob do ? what is the error appearing in Hangfire dashborad ? Does the job eternally fails once it has failed one time ? ....

Comment: ScheduleInactiveJob calls a business logic to perform. Regarding hangfire dashboard error message, I am not seeing anywhere only ERROR with red background. So i am trying to catch the error and trigger the job again..How to implement that?